# Do Redis and Resque need to be launched from same directory as app? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Do Redis and Resque need to be launched from the same directory as the app I'm planning to run?

Typically I launch both `redis-server` and `TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES=* rake resque:work` before launching my application with `unicorn`.

But to be honest, I'm still figuring out Redis and Resque.

So what I'm wondering is the following:

Should Redis and Resque (as above) be launched from the same directory as the application I'm running?

Or can they be launched from any directory on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis can be launched from any directory as it doesn't have a dependency on your code base.

Resque should be launched from your application root as it does pick up your source code along according to the specific Rails environment you may point it to.